# How to minimize this expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I need to minimize the following expression with respect to $\theta$. In this expression $X$ is a $(N × 2)$ matrix that contains a column of 1's and an explanatory variable in the second column. $\theta_s$ is a parameter vector that contains a constant and the coefficient for the explanatory variable.

Maybe a bit unclear in the notation, but the index $i$ refers to the $N$ in the summation and $t$ refers to $T$ in the summation.

$$\sum_{NT} p_{i s}\left(y_{i t}-X \theta_s\right)^2$$

> **Q: What is the analytical expression of the optimal** $\theta$**?**

- Note 1: I got as a hint that I could use the WLS solutions, but I don't see how
- Note 2: The original problem is described here: [How to do the M-step in the EM algorithm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4818626/how-to-do-the-m-step-in-the-em-algorithm)

Comment: What does the index $s$ refer to?  It would help if you made your sums either $\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{t=1}^T$ or $\sum_{s=1}^N\sum_{t=1}^T$, or whatever it is that you want.

Comment: @Michael the original optimization problem is to optimize a matrix of parameters, where each column represents its own segment/s.

However as we split the optimization over the segments, the index s is just a result of the original notation, which can ignored here. 

Note that the subindex i refers the the "shop" and goes from 1,....,N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like $y_{it} - X\theta$ is a $N$-dimensional vector, so $(y_{it}-X\theta)^2$ does not make sense.

I think you want to minimize
$$\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{t=1}^Tp_i||y_{it}-X\theta||^2$$

---

Let us assume $p_i\geq 0$ for all $i$.
If you want, you can write this as a minimization of $$\sum_{i,t}||\sqrt{p_i}y_{it}-\sqrt{p_i}X\theta||^2$$ which can be written as a minimization of $$||a-M\theta||^2$$ for some vector $a$ and some matrix $M$.

---

However, it sounds like your vector $\theta$ has the form $\theta = (1,z) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ in which case you really have a function of one variable $z\in\mathbb{R}$, you can take a derivative with respect to $z$. Note that for known $v,z\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $z\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $$||v-rz||^2=(v-rz)^{\top}(v-rz)=||v||^2 - 2rv^{\top}z + ||r||^2z^2$$ So you have a sum of $NT$ such expressions, meaning your overall expression is of the form $a+bz+cz^2$ for some $c\geq 0$, where $a,b,c$ are sums of inner products of the data.